# Highest record in PL/SQL

Tags: plsql

I have created a query that displays highest returned items from a table. My query it works perfectly with no errors! However, I want an efficient way of converting the query to PL/SQL block. The purpose of conversion is to handle errors.

```
 SELECT ITEM_NO, MAX(QUANTITY) AS MAXIMUM 
 FROM ITEMS 
 WHERE CAT_NO >= (
      SELECT MAX(ITEM_NUM) FROM ORDER 
      WHERE STATUS IN('ONE ITEM RETURNED','ALL ITEMS RETURNED')
 )
 GROUP BY ITEM_NO
 ORDER BY ITEM_NO ASC;
```

Comment: Why do you want to convert that into a stored procedure? what is the real problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I want to reduce the size of this query into a block for inefficiency and errors handling .

Comment: Turning this query into a stored procedure won't reduce the size - it will make it actually bigger and slower

Comment: But how do I handle exception as this query part in my stored procedure!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way we do some exception handling in packages.  I altered it to use your code as an example.  Maybe you can use some ideas from it.

At the top, set a CONSTANT to the name of the procedure, and some variables to catch Oracle SQL error number and message in.  Then in the body of the procedure, there is an anonymous block containing the select.  First we set a variable to indicate where we are (err_loc) in case there are multiple locations where an error could be caught in one block.  Then the select is issued. If an error occurs, it's caught by the EXCEPTION clause. Error info from Oracle is caught in the err* variables, the err_string is built and then emailed via the UTL_MAIL package. RAISE raises the error so the program halts.  It's set up like this to be generic as possible, we can drop in the template, change the MBR_NAME, SQL, err_loc and that's it.

```
  PROCEDURE TEST_PROC AS
    MBR_NAME        CONSTANT VARCHAR2(100) := 'TEST_PROC';  -- For use in error handling. Package member name.
    err_nbr                  NUMBER;                        -- Holds a SQL error number if an exception occurs.
    err_msg                  VARCHAR2(1000);                -- Holds a SQL error message if an exception occurs.
    err_string               VARCHAR2(2000);

  BEGIN
    BEGIN
      err_loc := 'Selecting max quantity';      -- Email subject

      SELECT ITEM_NO, MAX(QUANTITY) AS MAXIMUM 
      FROM ITEMS 
      WHERE CAT_NO >= (SELECT MAX(ITEM_NUM) 
                       FROM ORDER 
                       WHERE STATUS IN('ONE ITEM RETURNED','ALL ITEMS RETURNED')
                      )
      GROUP BY ITEM_NO
      ORDER BY ITEM_NO ASC;
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
        err_nbr  := SQLCODE;
        err_msg  := SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 1000);
        err_string := 'ERROR: ' || err_nbr || ' occurred: ' || err_msg;

        -- PKG_NAME and err_email_recip set in the body.
        UTL_MAIL.send(sender     => PKG_NAME||'.'||MBR_NAME||'@yourcompany.com', 
                      recipients => err_email_recip,  
                      subject    => 'ERROR '|| err_loc, 
                      message    => CHR(13))||err_string);
        RAISE;
    END;
  END TEST_PROC;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I discovered a logical error in my query that is every time the quantity increase for 'ONE ITEM RETURNED','ALL ITEMS RETURNED'. The query still displays the old records without counting the new hightest quality record i.e. the first row!!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `cursors` and `records`. 
 
That way you have fetch data from the query and process the line if needed.

I don't have a database by hand to test my code, but this might give you an idea how a `cursor` and `record` work. 
In order to capture a `EXCEPTION` you could add an exception handler and let it log the `record` you where busy with when the exception occured.

```
DECLARE 
    CURSOR CursorName IS 
        SELECT  ColumnOne 
        FROM    TableA 
        WHERE   Name = 'Me';

    RecordNumber CursorName%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN 
    -- Fetch the records from the cursor. 
    OPEN CursorName; 
    LOOP
        FETCH CursorName INTO RecordNumber;

        -- Do something with the record. 

        EXIT WHEN CursorName %NOTFOUND;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE CursorName;
END;
/
```

Adding a error handeling would be done right above `END`:

```
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        -- Log error message. 
END;
/
```

Link: [Error handeling](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/exceptions/sqlerrm.php) 
Does that answer you question a bit?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have made a cursor as you stated in your comment, but the result is not accurate since I want only one record displayed as the highest value, I wonder if I can edit new code!

Comment: So you only want the highest value? Then you could also add to the query `WHERE RowNum = 1`. Basicly then you say, I only want the first  line displayed. And in the code you could remove the `LOOP`, and just say `OPEN CursorName;
FETCH CursorName  INTO RecordNumber;
CLOSE CursorName;`

Comment: Can I do it in a FOR LOOP ?

Comment: I think you can, that should work as well. You just need to have the `EXCEPTION` part in your code as well. When something goes wrong while the code is executing in the procedure, it will go to the `EXCEPTION` part.

Comment: MY SQL query doesn't count the new added records every time I increase the records! as returned based on the ONE ITEM RETURNED','ALL ITEMS RETURNED' statement! :(

Comment: Please provide some sample data